# Woocommerce change product style and display it on a page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Sorry in advance for my approximative english. I would like to change product page style on woocommerce for a specific product category (don't display pictures and some other important layout changes). Already made it and it works, the problem is that I would like to display these products on a single page. I tried using woocommerce integrated shortcode [product_page id=$id], the problem is that the custom style and layout I created on content-single-product.php (in woocommerce folder) is not applied using this shortcode. I tried to copy my script on class-ws-shortcodes.php (woocommerce folder) but it didn't worked. What should I do to display the products on a specific page, with the real style of these products page (the custom one I created), and not the woocommerce shortcode one?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: check URL : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-page-11 It might help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution replacing term_id by product category id, and "single-product-seperateCategory" by "single-product-custom" (name of my category and of the php file copied in theme folder) but it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this, it just depends on whether you want to edit `single-product.php` or `content-single-product.php`. Both will get you to the same end result.

To do the former, you can use default WordPress functionality and filter the template under given conditions via [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include)

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_29984159_custom_category_template' );
function so_29984159_custom_category_template( $template ){
    if ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'product' && has_term( 'custom_category', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'single-product-custom.php' );
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Or if you'd rather create a custom `content-product.php` template part, you can use WooCommerce's `wc_get_template_part` which works in pretty much the same way.
Technically I think you can use the same conditional logic, but I tweaked it here to point out the variables WooCommerce makes available at the filter.

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', 'so_29984159_custom_content_template_part', 10, 3 );
function so_29984159_custom_content_template_part( $template, $slug, $name ){
    if ( $slug == 'content' && $name == 'product' && has_term( 'custom_category', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'content-product-custom.php' );
    }
    return $template;
}
```

In either case the `single-product-custom.php` or `content-product-custom.php` would be in your theme's root folder. To put them somewhere else, just change the path in the `locate_template()` argument.

Comment: I'll check it out thanks for this detailed answer, hope it will work

Comment: I didn't test anything so be wary of stray ; or ), but I think the idea should work.

Comment: My custom template was not well made (directly edited content-single-product.php), so I've created a content-single-product-custom.php file.

And I replaced wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );  in single-product.php to load the template for the category named custom.

Better organisation but same results: example.com/product/myproduct (the product page) displays the product with custom template, but woocommerce product_page shortcode don't.

Your code: Not sure where I should add this filter (template loader files?) not used to hooks and filters, I only use them since few days

Comment: If you use my second filter you don't need to replace `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' )` at all. Either code snippet belongs in your theme's `functions.php`. If you need more help understanding filters I wrote what I think is a pretty good [tutorial on how to use filters](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/?p=455)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do coding in wordpress's file i.e. page.php to modify woocommerce pages. Its wrong way. You simply override WooCommerce pages into your theme folder and then modify any pages which you want to do. All templates/pages are located in a woocommerce/templates folder.

Here you can find documentation.

```
 http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
```

Comment: Yes I know I made a mistake in my question, I wrote my custom template in content-single-product.php, not in page.php

Answer (score 0):

edit woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php for single product view

Comment: This is what I did, and it works, products of specific category I chose have a different template. The problem is that I want to display these products on a wordpress page. But when I use woocommerce produc_page shortcode to do so, surprisingly (well it surprised me), it doesn't diplay the products with my custom template. In other words: http://www.example.com/product/myproduct/ display the product with my custom template (located in content-single-product.php), but when I try to display the product on another wordpress page with woocommerce shortcode, it doesn't work.

Comment: i understand your problem. do one thing in content-single-product.php add if condition for templates. for example if you want to display differnet styple for product under XYZ template then add." if ( is_page_template('XYZ.php') ) ".  you can write specific code inside it for that template.